# Windows Phone ContainerContentChanging Phase always 0

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

Using a ListView on WinRT WP8.1 app:

I'm trying to use ContainerContentChanging event on a ListView as so -

```
private void ListOnContainerContentChanging(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
    {
        var viewer = args.ItemContainer.ContentTemplateRoot as View;
        if (viewer == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (args.InRecycleQueue)
        {
            viewer.ClearData();
        }
        else if (args.Phase == 0)
        {
            viewer.ShowPlaceholder(args.Item as ViewModel);

            args.RegisterUpdateCallback(this.ContainerContentChangingDelegate);
        }
        else if (args.Phase == 1)
        {
            // Load
            args.RegisterUpdateCallback(this.ContainerContentChangingDelegate);
        }
        else if (args.Phase == 2)
        {
            // Load more
            args.RegisterUpdateCallback(this.ContainerContentChangingDelegate);
        }
        else if (args.Phase == 3)
        {
            // Show images
        }

        args.Handled = true;
    }
```

The issue I'm having is Phase property on the ContainerContentChangingEventArgs is always 0 when scrolling to view more items.

(All works correctly for the items loaded in the initial view - it's only when I start scrolling that no items get updated past their placeholder.

Any ideas why hase property would not be updating?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the phase number when you register the update callback.

Your code should look something like the following:

```
private void ListOnContainerContentChanging(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
{
    var viewer = args.ItemContainer.ContentTemplateRoot as View;
    if (viewer == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (args.InRecycleQueue)
    {
        viewer.ClearData();
    }
    else if (args.Phase == 0)
    {
        viewer.ShowPlaceholder(args.Item as ViewModel);

        args.RegisterUpdateCallback(1, this.ContainerContentChangingDelegate);
    }
    else if (args.Phase == 1)
    {
        // Load
        args.RegisterUpdateCallback(2, this.ContainerContentChangingDelegate);
    }
    else if (args.Phase == 2)
    {
        // Load more
        args.RegisterUpdateCallback(3, this.ContainerContentChangingDelegate);
    }
    else if (args.Phase == 3)
    {
        // Show images
    }

    args.Handled = true;
}
```